Verification of formula for positive and negative variation in Folland's
Let $F\in BV$ be real-valued, and denote by $T_F(x)$ the total variation function of $F$, $$T_F(x)=\sup\left\{\sum_1^n |F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})|:n\in\mathbb N,-\infty<x_0<\cdots<x_n=x\right\}.$$ Then we can write $F=\frac12 (T_F+F)-\frac12(T_F-F)$, where $\frac12 (T_F\pm F)$ are increasing. Now, Folland claims in real analysis text (page 103) that $$\frac12 (T_F\pm F)=\sup\left\{\sum_1^n [F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})]^\pm :x_0<\cdots<x_n=x\right\}\mp\frac12 F(-\infty),$$where $x^+=\max(x,0)=\frac12 (|x|+x)$ and $x^-=\max(-x,0)=\frac12(|x|-x)$. Could somebody help me verify this equality? (Note that in the book it says $\pm\frac12 F(-\infty)$, but the errata says it should be $\mp\frac12 F(-\infty)$.)
Attempt: Let's just assume $\frac12 (T_F+F)$. Then $$[F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})]^+=\frac12 |F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})|+\frac12 (F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})).$$Now, $\sum_1^n (F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1}))=F(x)-F(x_0)$. But this is where I'm stuck. How do I simplify $$\sup\left\{\frac12\sum_1^n |F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})|+\frac12 (F(x)-F(x_0)):x_0<\cdots<x_n=x\right\}?$$
I know of $\sup (A+B)=\sup A+\sup B$ and $\sup cA=c\sup A, c>0$, but I'm a bit uncertain about these identities and if they apply here, since the above is a set of functions. We also have $\sup_A (f+g)\leq \sup_A f+\sup_A g$, but we don't want inequality.

Thanks for OP for helping with this answer thanks to their kind comments.
We have, when $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$:
$$(\sup A) + c = \sup (A + c)$$
where $A + c := A + \{c\} = \{a + c \mid a \in A\}$ and this is the principle that I'll use here (which is really is just an application of the formula $\sup (A+B) = \sup A + \sup B$ you mentioned!).
I'll leave out the mention of what $n$ and the $x_j$s are just to make everything fit on one line since the expressions are quite long, but they're always implied. That is, I'll only write the relevant information like a change from $-\infty < x_0$ to $-\infty = x_0$ and such.
First of all, let's prove that $T_F(x) = T(x)$ where:
$$T(x) := \sup\left\{\sum_1^n |F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})|, -\infty = x_0 < x_1\right\}$$
Of course, $T_F(x) \leq T(x)$, so it suffices to prove that $T(x) \leq T_F(x)$.
Consider $\varepsilon > 0$. By the usual properties of suprema, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $-\infty = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_n = x$ such that:
$$T(x) \leq \sum_1^n |F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
Now choose $-\infty < y_0 < x_1$ such that $\big||F(x_1) - F(y_0)| - |F(x_1)-F(-\infty)|\big| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, which exists by the existence of the limit at $-\infty$ of the function:
$$y \mapsto |F(x_1) - F(y)|$$
thanks to the continuity of $|\cdot|$ at $F(x_1) - F(-\infty)$.
This then yields, defining $y_j := x_j$ for $j \geq 1$:
$$\begin{split}T(x) &\leq \sum_2^n |F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})| + |F(x_1) - F(-\infty)| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
&\leq \sum_2^n |F(y_j)-F(y_{j-1})| + |F(y_1) - F(y_0)| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\\
&\leq \sum_1^n |F(y_j)-F(y_{j-1})| + \varepsilon\\
&\leq T_F(x) + \varepsilon\end{split}$$
Since this holds for all $\varepsilon > 0$, we obtain $T(x) \leq T_F(x)$, thus $T(x) = T_F(x)$, and we are done with this subclaim.
The proof in the original version of this answer used the triangle inequality, but this new proof circumvents that and is now applicable to other such expressions, i.e. with this reasoning you can show the following:
$$\sup\left\{\sum_1^n (F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1}))^\pm, -\infty < x_0 < x_1\right\} = \sup\left\{\sum_1^n (F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1}))^\pm, -\infty = x_0 < x_1\right\}$$
We now get:
$$\begin{split}(T_F \pm F)(x) &= \sup\left\{\sum_1^n |F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})|, -\infty = x_0 < x_1\right\} \pm F(x)\\
&= \sup\left\{\sum_1^n |F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})| \pm F(x)\right\} \\
&= \sup\left\{\sum_1^n |F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})| \pm (F(x) - F(-\infty))\right\} \pm F(-\infty)\\
&= \sup\left\{\sum_1^n |F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})| \pm \left(\sum_1^n F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})\right) \right\} \pm F(-\infty)\\
&= 2\sup\left\{\sum_1^n (F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1}))^\pm \mid -\infty = x_0 < x_1 \right\} \pm F(-\infty)\\
&= 2\sup\left\{\sum_1^n (F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1}))^\pm \mid -\infty < x_0 < x_1 \right\} \pm F(-\infty)\end{split}$$
and we are done.
This reasoning also seems to suggest that the erratum you mention might just be wrong, i.e. it is indeed $\pm F(-\infty)$ and not $\mp$.

Thank you for your answer! When the author writes $$\sup\left{\sum_1^n [F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})]^\pm :x_0<\cdots<x_n=x\right}$$is $x_0<\cdots<x_n=x$ short for $n\in\mathbb N, -\infty<x_0<\cdots<x_n=x$?

@psie That's what I'd interpret it as, I think. That's why I believe I haven't answered fully the question.

Where in proving that the last $\sup$ in your answer is equal to one where $-\infty < x_0$ did you get stuck? Isn't it just the same argument as the one for $T_F=T$?

@psie The positive/negative part doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality, so there are multiple cases to study. I'll try coming back to it later.

I've been taking a closer look at this, and I don't think you need to use triangle inequality when proving $T_F(x)\geq T(x)$. What you need is $$||F(x_1) - F(-\infty)| - |F(x_1) - F(y_0)|| \leq \varepsilon/2,$$ which you don't need triangle inequality for since $$|F(x_1) - F(y)| \to |F(x_1) - F(-\infty)|$$ as $y \to -\infty$. What do you think about this? To be specific, in $$T(x) \leq \sum_2^n |F(x_j)-F(x_{j-1})| + |F(x_1) - F(-\infty)| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2},$$wouldn't it work to use the above?

@psie I was busy, I just now saw your comment. I've edited my partial answer into a full answer, thank you for the help!
